# How to keep additional URL parameters with Algolia search and pagination

Tags: javascript, filter, algolia, facet, instantsearch.js

I have some filters predefined and a query parameters in my URL. I need to add some other parameter to the URL to keep track of the source of the user and some other purposes. But, whenever I do a new refinement or entered into a new page(pagination). The additional parameters got deleted. How can I preserve that parameters till I go to any other routes?

Answer (score 4):

In order to preserve your existing url parameters, you have to create your own URL in the router.history.

For that, grab the current `location.search` and merge in the `routeState` when you search or remove the `routeState` object when you exit the search.

I hope the following code helps and if someone has any correction, I'm happy to hear them.

```js
const algoliaAppId = 'APP_ID';
const algoliaApiKey = 'API_KEY';
const algoliaIndex = 'instant_search';

const search = instantsearch({
  indexName: algoliaIndex,
  algoliasearch(algoliaAppId, algoliaApiKey),
  routing: {
    router: instantsearch.routers.history({

      createURL({ qsModule, location, routeState }) {
        // current search params 
        const indexState = routeState[algoliaIndex] || {};
        const { origin, pathname, hash, search } = location;
        // grab current query string and convert to object
        const queryParameters = qsModule.parse(search.slice(1)) || {};
        
        // if there is an active search
        if (Object.keys(indexState).length ){
          // merge the search params with the current query params
          Object.assign(queryParameters, routeState);
        }else{
          // remove the search params
          delete queryParameters[algoliaIndex];
        }

        let queryString = qsModule.stringify(queryParameters);

        if(queryString.length){
          queryString = `?${queryString}`;
        }

        return `${origin}${pathname}${queryString}${hash}`;
      },

    })
  }

});

search.start();
```